# Best and worst case running time of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to calculate the best and worst case running time of following algorithm. My matter is do I need to consider `i*i` in second loop? And to get the complexity of that loop as `Q(N^2)`?

```
    for i=1 to 2*n do
       for j=1 to i*i do
          for k=1 to k<j do
             if j%i==0 then
                 sum=sum+1;
```

this is the full code

```
    procedure proc(n:integer){
    var i,j,k :integer
    var sum: integer
   begin
 sum=0;
 for i=1 to 2*n do
 begin
       for j=1 to i*i do
       begin 
              for k=1 to k<j do
              begin
                       if j%i==0 then
                       sum=sum+1;
                       end if
                       k=k+1;
    end
   j=j+1;
  end 
 i=i+i;
 end
 end }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyze it from inside out.

```
         if j%i==0 then
             sum=sum+1;
```

This takes constant time every time it is reached.

```
      for k=1 to k<j do
```

The most inner loop runs `O(j)` times, once for each value of k from 1 to j (exclusive). So far we have `O(j*1) = O(j)`

```
   for j=1 to i*i do
```

For the middle loop - each value of `j` has to do job in the complexity of `O(j)`. This means, you are going to need for this entire loop (for each value of `i`):

```
1 + 2 + .... + i*i = i*i*(i*i+1)/2 = i^2(i^2+1)/2  [sum of arithmetic progression]
```

The above is in `O(i^4)`

```
for i=1 to 2*n do
```

`Sum{i^2*(i^2+1)/2 | i from 1 to 2n }` [which is in `O(n^5)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%7Bi%5E2*%28i%5E2%2B1%29%2F2%7D%20i%20from%201%20to%202n)

Comment: @janithachanuka It makes no difference from the original analysis

Comment: ado janiya uba prashna pathare mekatath damma neda?

Comment: @heshjse- thambena deyak kala nidaganin ban. it will work (y)

Comment: @amit- got it (y). and what about the best case running time of this algorithm?